# How do I know the remote process is running, or complete?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using the Python library Paramiko to run a command over ssh on another server. The problem I'm facing is that the `SSHClient.exec_command()` call returns immediately, sending me `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` and giving me no other way I can see to tell if the process is still running or not. I thought that I might try monitoring to see if the streams it returns are still open, but I can't find any way to do this except by trying to read from `stdout` or `stderr`, or write to `stdin` and waiting to receive a `ValueError`. Can anyone tell me of something I've missed that should work instead?

Comment: Use the channel API  ? http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/channel.html

Comment: You may want to start using Fabric: http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: @ReutSharabani Thanks. Fabric looks interesting. I'll check it out sometime. For now, I've managed to get things working with Paramiko.

Comment: Cool. Just so you know - fabric saved me many hours of implementing things that are already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to advice from @fixxxer I found what I needed to know. My test code now looks like this:

```
import paramiko
import time

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('localhost', username='user', password='password')

transport = ssh.get_transport()
channel = transport.open_session()
channel.exec_command('./exec_test.py')

status = channel.recv_exit_status()
```

This works marvellously. It blocks until the command is finished, then allows me to continue.

Comment: Word of warning - this will deadlock if command output is large enough to fill the pipe.